# aggregation on json column

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have table with a string column with JSON of collection of objects. Assume the objects are words.

I want to aggregate in select the most popular words ( like the map-reduce example). The data is NOT in nested records in Bigquery. I understand I need to use JSON_EXTRACT.

for example: 
userid   words

---

123   "{"totalItems":2,"items":[{"word":"drink"},{"word":"food"}]}",
456   "{"totalItems":3,"items":[{"word":"food"},{"word":"dog"},"word":"drink"}]}" ,
123   "{"totalItems":1,"items":[{"word":"drink"}]} "

The result should be :
3 Drink
2 food
1 dog

and if I would group it by user, it would be:
Userid  count  word
123     2     drink,
123     1     food,
456     1     food, .... etc...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**By Word**:

```
SELECT id, word, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM (
  SELECT id, REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r':"(\w+)"') AS word,
  FROM (
    SELECT id, SPLIT(JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$.items')) AS item
    FROM 
    (SELECT 123 AS id, '{"totalItems":2,"items":[{"word":"drink"},{"word":"food"}]}' AS items), 
    (SELECT 456 AS id, '{"totalItems":3,"items":[{"word":"food"},{"word":"dog"},{"word":"drink"}]}' AS items), 
    (SELECT 123 AS id, '{"totalItems":1,"items":[{"word":"drink"}]}' AS items) 
  )
)
GROUP BY id, word
```

**By User, Word**:

```
SELECT word, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM (
  SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r':"(\w+)"') AS word,
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$.items')) AS item
    FROM 
    (SELECT 123 AS id, '{"totalItems":2,"items":[{"word":"drink"},{"word":"food"}]}' AS items), 
    (SELECT 456 AS id, '{"totalItems":3,"items":[{"word":"food"},{"word":"dog"},{"word":"drink"}]}' AS items), 
    (SELECT 123 AS id, '{"totalItems":1,"items":[{"word":"drink"}]}' AS items) 
  )
)
GROUP BY word
```

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail answer is good! Note that there is some adjustments needed, that were performed with SPLIT and REGEXP_EXTRACT, as the JSON_EXTRACT functions don't handle arrays well enough.

An alternative, in case you want to work with a BigQuery JavaScript UDF:

```
SELECT userid, word, COUNT(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM
  js(
    // I wish you had given me a sample table instead when asking the question
    (SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT 123 AS id, '{"totalItems":2,"items":[{"word":"drink"},{"word":"food"}]}' AS items), 
      (SELECT 456 AS id, '{"totalItems":3,"items":[{"word":"food"},{"word":"dog"},{"word":"drink"}]}' AS items), 
      (SELECT 123 AS id, '{"totalItems":1,"items":[{"word":"drink"}]}' AS items) 
    ),
    // Input columns.
    id, items,
    // Output schema.
    "[{name: 'word', type:'string'},
     {name: 'userid', type:'integer'}]",
     // The function.
     "function(r, emit) { 
      x=JSON.parse(r.items)
      x.items.forEach(function(entry) {
        emit({word:entry.word, userid:r.id});
      });     
    }"
  )
)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Both looks good, Felipe, just to be clear, you wrote that REGEX_EXTRACT & Spilt needs adjustments?  what are they? And will JS UDF will work better regardless?  thx a lot

Comment: I mean, look at the REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r':"(\w+)"') that Mikhail's query needs. I would probably do the same, unless the strings within 'word' are more than simple words. Then I would use UDFs.